# Log Analyzer for IIS logs

Tags: logging

I have plenty of programs that will parse IIS access logs and save them in a relational database (MS SQL or MySQL).
I am looking for a good interface that will allow me to query those logs.

For example, when our server error log shows that there was an exception in the application, it includes the user's IP address. I would like to have a program/web-interface where I can just put in information about that request (like IP address, time, url, etc.) and it will give me all of the log lines that relate to that request (that one and before and after it).

Alternatively, a log management system that can take care of automatically retrieving the newest logs and automatically processing it might work too.
I have used Awstats to get statistical information from log files, and I know that it can pull lines from the active log file and remember where it was up to in the file for the next run. (You can correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think Awstats can give you the history of a particular IP address or automatically pull logs.)

Comment: I suppose the type of log (IIS, Apache, Firewall, SMTP, etc) does not matter as long as it is in a standard machine-readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know for a fact but we do something similar using Splunk but against Cisco/Apache/ESX/Firewall logs - just a suggestion.

Comment: Not sure why I just noticed this answer. I will try it out and see if it works for me. For now, I am marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own parsing with the Microsoft LogParser tool (you would still have to manage logs yourself).  There is a log management solution from IISLogs.com that we see in production quite a bit.

If you want something that will do the analysis for your in realtime, and manage the logs automatically, check out [LeanSentry](https://www.leansentry.com).

(disclosure: I am a developer on the team).

LeanSentry will automatically analyze the logs and give you traffic reports, errors, detect hacking traffic, etc.